# ChunkedEncodingError con requests python

Tags: python, django, apache, python-requests

Estoy tratando de conectar a una API para recibir datos que usaré en mi app. Utilizo ***Django 1.9*** junto a ***Python 2.7*** y tengo el proyecto montado en local con el servidor Apache, usando el ***mod_wsgi***.

Para hacer las peticiones a la API utilizo ***requests***, pero al hacer una petición post, pasándole un código que obtengo en una petición anterior y una cookie, Django me da error:

> ChunkedEncodingError "Connection broken: error(10054, 'Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto')

He buscando en internet sobre ello y la verdad es que no me ha quedado claro si es del mod_swgi, si es que django no puede leer chunked response...y no encuentro solución al problema. También he mirado el log de Apache, pero no aparece ningún error relacionado.

Tengo otras peticiones get y post y en ninguna me da este error...
Esta es la línea en django que me da el error:

```
header = {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','Cookie':cookie}

requests.post('http://direccionapi.es/auth/OAuth20/Token',{'Authorization':'Basic d2Vdfdsfdf','code':codigo,'grant_type':'authorization_code','redirect_uri':ip,'response_type': 'code'},headers = header)
```

¿Alguien que sepa qué está ocurriendo y alguna solución?

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el método `post()` necesita pasarle los parámetros como `data=`. Además, creo que la clave de `Authorization` debe ir en la cabecera, no en el cuerpo.

```
header = {
    'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Cookie':cookie,
    'Authorization':'Basic d2Vdfdsfdf'
}

requests.post('http://direccionapi.es/auth/OAuth20/Token',data={'code':codigo,'grant_type':'authorization_code','redirect_uri':ip,'response_type': 'code'},headers=header)
```